# Generate C# class from JSON stream and Parse this stream

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net, deserialization

I want to generate C# class from this ([JSON DATA](http://pastebin.com/kfQ8KgEg)) but http://json2csharp.com/ can't generate the C# class. The JSON should be valid (http://jsonlint.com/). Can you help me?

And when I create the class form JSON I only use something like this:

```
MyNewClass test = ser.Deserialize<MyNewClass>(response);
```

Comment: are you trying to generate a c# *class* or *object*?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any class since your json is `List<List<string>>`

```
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<List<string>>>(json);
```

or using Json.Net

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(json);
```

That is all....

```
foreach (var list in result)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your C# class. So, for example;

```
public class Wrapper
{   
    public List<CustomObject> Data { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObject 
{ 
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and then deserialize with `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()`

```
Wrapper wrapper = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Wrapper>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easyest and simplest way in 2 steps without any 3rth party libraries

1-
go to http://json2csharp.com/ and let the generator to create your c# classes

2-

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url);    
YourJSonClass obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourJSonClass>();
```